# Blazor Chrome caching issues

Tags: web, caching, dll, single-page-application, blazor

I have this Blazor SPA I have published to IIS on a webhotel. My problem is that Chrome is somehow caching my Blazor assembly so no matter how many times I redeploy I still get the old dll. I can start up a new clean Chrome with *chrome --disable-application-cache --incognito* and that does indeed get the fresh dll but how do I fix this properly?
Kind regards

Answer (score 12):

The following helps IF you don't want PWA features.

I started my project with PWA (just in case I wanted it later) but it turned out to cause this problem even when simply browsing. Tried adding comments or versioning to service-worker.published.js but that didn't help. I'm using Blazor version 3.2.1.

With PWA. When checking the cache in the browser I do see the latest service-worker.published.js appearing, and a new offline cache does get downloaded. But the browser keeps using the older ones for a reason beyond my understanding.

[image]

To remove PWA:

1. Delete the following files from wwwroot:

> ```
> /wwwroot/manifest.json
> /wwwroot/service-worker.js
> /wwwroot/service-worker.published.js
> ```

2. Delete this line from /wwwroot/index.html

> ```
> <script>navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');</script>
> ```

3. Delete those lines from your csproj file

> ```
> <ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>service-worker-assets.js</ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>
> <ServiceWorker Include="wwwroot\service-worker.js" PublishedContent="wwwroot\service-worker.published.js" />
> ```

Comment: Thanks Waleed. The funny thing is that I don't have the same problem anymore. And I am even on Blazor 3.2.1

Comment: Maybe you didn't enable PWA in the first place in this project?

Comment: Thanks for your steps for removing a PWA.

Comment: This removed PWA, but does not fix the cache issue

Answer (score 1):

The cache issue is pretty strange. I had a lot of trouble solving it as well and what seemed to work was that I in Chrome installed it as an app when it had loaded the old cache. I could do the force full refresh, but as soon as I did a new regular refresh it would go back to the old DLL cache. But after installing it as an app in Chrome, inside that app which I could uninstall it, and it also had the option to remove it from Chrome as well. Then it finally began loading my new version of the app... where I had done as Waleed Al Harthi suggests, to remove PWA and avoid this issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly like you do it. But of cause there are also other ways.

1. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> in the Browser -> Select ***Network*** -> Check ***Disable cache***
2. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> in the Browser -> In developer mode <kbd>R Click</kbd> on **reload** -> Select ***hard reload***
3. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to hard reload
4. Your way but create a shortcut for it.
5. Disable cache with code (not recommended and i would have to lookup how)

Comment: OP wants to show the new version to every visitor of his SPA. Every visitor should not have to hard reload just to see the new version.

Answer (score 0):

[Enable it as a PWA](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazorPWA.MSBuild/)

Then you can control the cache with a property in your project. 
The client will cache your code until you tell it to update - the user will be told there is an update and should reload the page - at this point it will update.