# How to ensure a Blazor web assembly is refreshed on new version?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

What do I need to do to force a web assembly Blazor application stored on an Azure static web site to refresh when a new version is uploaded (through GitHub)?

I am seeing conflicting and possibly outdated information:
first [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22353#issuecomment-636765665) which does not do the trick for me.

Next [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169801/forcing-reload-of-blazor-client-after-publishing-changes) which seems to imply I need to add a second service-worker in addition to service-worker.published.js.  Is that the case?

***Edit: I have added the following line at the top of service-worker.published.js and keep changing the number, with no effect.

`const CACHE_VERSION = 0.822;`

I'm sure it is a simple solution - which should really be the default by the way...

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but I did find that changing the cache_version doesn't immediately trigger a new version. From what I noticed on the first load after the new version has deployed (and you change your version number) the browser should recognize that a new service-worker is available. At this point, it hasn't refreshed anything yet. After closing the browser and opening the page again it should use the new version. This isn't a great option, so I do hope someone comes up with a better way.