# Clearing browser cache when deploying new update in Blazor WASM application

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

We are developing a web application using **Blazor WebAssembly** (.NET 8 Preview) and IIS for hosting. Whenever we publish a new release, our users don't get new changes unless they clear browser history or hard reload. And when we upgrade the .NET version and nuget packages, users must clear browser history to use the application, otherwise they get an error on console (attached screenshot). It's clear that browser cache is causing the issue. Is there any way to clear the browser cache from code side? Do you have any other suggestions to overcome the problem?
[image: Console Error]

Comment: Maybe these would help you :
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20408
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/web-development/blazor-wasm-pwa-applications-updates-cache-busting-with/m-p/3920976
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169801/forcing-reload-of-blazor-client-after-publishing-changes