# Blazor wasm hosted keeps loading Blazor app when their is a controller action to deal with page on the server side

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I'll try and explain my problem.
So its Blazor wasm hosted (Client and Server projects).
I'm hoping to have a mixture of some pages that are served up by the server using MVC controller actions and also the Blazor app that deals with everything else.

I have a page   /heat-maps/351
There is a controller action that deals with this request, the Blazor app won't do anything with that url.

So in a browser where I have already been on the Blazor app if I go to {my-domain}/heat-maps/351  (in a new tab) then it doesn't serve up the proper page it just loads the Blazor app and says page can't be found.

If i go to that same url {my-domain}/heat-maps/351 in a different broswer where I haven't already gone to the blazor app then it works as intended, the controller action kicks in and the page generated on the server is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem I was having is because the app is an offline PWA and there is a service worker intercepting the requests and serving up a cached copy of index.html instead of making a request to the server for urls that I intended to be served by the server.

When I removed PWA from my Blazor web app (by following steps on below link) it solved my issue.
[Blazor Chrome caching issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60613457/blazor-chrome-caching-issues)